# Does it make sense to plot train and test results on a common ROC graph?

Tags: spss, roc

I am building a model using SPSS with 80% of my data. I can plot a ROC curve for both the training set and separately for the test set. I can´t find a way to plot both on the same graph.
Since both sensitivity and sensibility vary between 0 and 1, this seems posible to do.
My question is: does it make sense to directly compare both curves, in other words, is it statistically valid?

Comment: You can certainly compare the area under the curves (AUC). This is sometimes called the out of sample AUC shrinkage. You could plot them both to look at the shape of the curves, but that shouldn't change in any important way. I don't know how you can superimpose the curves using SPSS, but maybe someone else does. It should be possible, it is with other software (eg, R).

Comment: What insights does an ROC curve give you, i.e., what is your reason for drawing it?

Comment: The ROC curve allows me to see the behavior of my model in specific risk regions, for example in the area with sensitivities < .20. Regarding my question, what I would like to check is if in this interest zone, the behaviour with the test dataset is similar to the train dataset. I don't really care what happens in the region with sensitivities > 0.20.   I would like to know if this comparison will tell me this.

Comment: @gung - +1, yet when you say the shape "shouldn't change in any important way" - that I think is the main point of the question, to ask whether superimposition is a valid way of checking that.  imo superimposition would allow only an informal/impressionistic check.  It will be hard to test specific differences, e.g., if at a sensitivity of .1, specificity is __ in the training set but only ___ in the test set.

Comment: From what I've read, visually comparing ROC curves is an easy way to compare models, even though there are statistics which can give a more exact result. It is in this sense that I would like to see if my results with test data are relatively similar to train or not.